# Выборка с использование нескольких таблиц?

Tags: mysql, sql, выборка

Есть таблица `cats` и таблица `sales`.

В `sales` хранятся предложения `(id, need, ican)`, а в `cats` описание предложений `(id, title)`. В `sales` в `need` и `ican` пишутся значения `id` из `cats`.

Cats:

```
id|   title
-----------------
1 | уборка дома
2 | ремонт машины
3 | мойка окон
```

Sales:

```
id|need|ican
------------
1 | 2  | 1
2 | 3  | 3
3 | 1  | 3
```

Нужно вывести sales привязав к ней cats взяв оттуда title к need и к ican.

Конструируем запрос:

```
SELECT sales.id AS sales_id,
       cats.title AS cats_title
FROM sales, cats
WHERE sales.need = cats.id
      AND sales.ican = cats.id
```

В итоге - пусто, ответа нет.

Вопрос такой, можно ли вывести и `need` и `ican` одним этим запросом, может использовать вложенные запросы, есть ли более эффективный способ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы используете соединение таблиц, при котором просите, чтобы значение `id` и `need` в таблице `sales` должны быть одинаковы, что собственно неверно, поэтому выдаст пустую строку.

Используйте два соединения с таблицами:

```
select s.id, c1.title need_title,
       c2.title ican_title
from sales s join cats c1 on s.need = c1.id
     join cats c2 on s.ican = c2.id
order by s.id
```

Пример на [sqlfiddle с ответом](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/779336/6/0).

Comment: По моему, я только что потерял девственность в области составления запросов mysql :)

Answer (score 4):

Делайте через `left join`

```
SELECT 
sales.id AS sales_id,
cat_need.title AS cats_need_title,
cat_ican  .title as cats_ican_title

FROM sales
left join  cats cat_need on sales.need = cat_need.id
left join  cats cat_ican  on sales.ican = cat_ican.id
```

Answer (score 1):

LEFT JOIN должен по идее помочь

```
SELECT A.id sales_id, B.aw_textad_id cats_title
FROM sales A 
LEFT JOIN cats B ON A.sales.need = B.id
WHERE A.ican = B.id
```